# Common Lisp - What's wrong with my debugger?

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, slime

I'm trying to run this code:

```
(defparameter *digits-string* (uiop:read-file-string "day08.txt"))

(defparameter shape '(25 6))

(defun read-file-into-layers (filepath layer-w layer-h)
  (with-open-file (stream filepath)
    (do ((char (read-char stream) (read-char stream))
         (layer-size (* layer-w layer-h))
         (layers nil)
         (layer nil)
         (i nil))
        ((not (digit-char-p char)) layers)
      (when (null layer) (setf layer (make-array layer-size)
                               i 0))
      (setf (aref layer i) (digit-char-p char))
      (incf i)
      (when (= i layer-size) (progn (push layers layer)
                                    (setf layer nil
                                          i 0))))))
```

*(https://github.com/AlbertoEAF/advent_of_code_2019/blob/d0a331157cbb3f37a16ae92f3cc2c56a35b3e00e/common-lisp/day08.lisp#L14-L28 + day08.txt for https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/8)*

which is returning nil, not sure why (the file contains a single line with 15k digits and a newline at the end).

I'm trying to debug with:

```
;; 1) Set maximum debug level
(declaim (optimize (speed 0) (space 0) (debug 3)))
;; 2) Recompile the full module + C-u C-c C-c on that function (don't know if that last part is needed)
;; 3) step:
(step (READ-file-into-layers "day08.txt" 25 6))
```

I still don't see almost any variable and stepping only stops at `(read-char stream)` and `(incf i)`, nothing else? And almost no variables are defined!

[image]

Also, if I press "e" to evaluate some expressions, even though at times some variables don't appear on the stacktrace, in this case it reports that they're not defined at all.

Any ideas of why the debugger is having this strange behaviour? Or is it just my code that is completely broken? Still, the debugger would be most helpful in this case if it worked :)

Comment: I debugged with prints and the issue was in the push, the arguments were reversed.
Still, that's not my point, my question still is why the debugger is acting like this and is not helping at all, and how to make it work properly without having to fill my code with prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that your compiler is too smart.  When you take a close look, then because of the inversed `push` form, you only ever set `layer` and `layers` to `nil`.  At one point, `layer` becomes `(nil)` only to be reverted to `nil` directly after that.  If all these no-ops get thrown out, not much is left to step.

You could try to glean whether this is the case by disassembling your compiled function using `disassemble`.

Comment: Thank you, wow! Will check if it is the case and report back :)

Comment: It is the case @Svante, however, even then, I cannot step through the setf calls.
Say you have this function (stupid code example), how could you debug it through stepping? Is it possible to step into setf as well?

(defun f (list)
  (setf (elt list 0) 1)
  (setf (elt list 1) 2)
  list)

(step (f (list 0 0 0 0))) ?

Comment: `Setf` is a macro, which in this case expands to some nested `rplaca` form, which gets compiled to a few instructions, but no function call.

Comment: So you're saying there are some limitations to debugging interactively right?
Can I ask what do you do/suggest doing when you get complex programs and you want to debug and understand in more detail what's going on? (including such calls like macros and setf's in the middle of the code, which might be helpful to debug)?
Thank you!

Comment: For macros, all you can do is take a look at their expansion.  `Setf` is a macro.  Of the standard language tools, I mostly use `trace` and `break`.  Other than that I try to avoid complexity as best as I can so that I do not have to dig through too much at once.

Comment: Thanks @Svante! :D